# Without Ajax Reload WebPage on Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a Bootstrap Modal which contains HTML form . Now on the Submit button click event of the form , i need to reload (refresh) the webpage. I am not using Ajax , My Server side code is getting called from form's form Action method.How to reload the webpage , in this case ?..Here is my HTML..

```
<div class="modal fade" id="StudentModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="StudentModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
 <form action="~/GetStudent" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" id="frmStudent">
    <div class="modal-footer">
       <div class="pull-right">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="save" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Save</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Close</button>
       </div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

and here is my Submit button click event..

```
$('#save').on('click', function () {
  $("#frmStudent").submit();
});
```

Please help me to get it done..Thanks..

Comment: First of all, you do not need a click handler here as `type='submit'` will do that for you. To reload the page, redirect the user on the very page once server side form handling is done!

Comment: @RayonDabre With out Click handler my Modal Form is not getting closed..

Comment: Do you mean form is not being submitted ? That should not happen unless there is some script which is preventing it.

Comment: @RayonDabre Form is submitting but Bootstrap Modal is not getting closed

Comment: You can close the `modal` using `elem.modal('hide');` but as form is submitting, there is no point in closing the modal..

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('#frmStudent').submit(function () {

  // Do your stuff here (on form Submit)

});
```